# How do you start a SharePoint 2010 workflow every day?

Tags: sharepoint, timer, workflow, designer

I am constructing a workflow that sends out emails when a date from a date column is 30 days from the current day.  How can I go about starting the workflow each day?  I would like to avoid using third party software and/or PowerShell.

Here is what my workflow looks like:

[workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSfAR.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to avoid powershell then you shouldn't tag it with Powershell? :-)

Answer (score 0):

try site-workflow - they are able to run at specific times:

https://amavs.wordpress.com/2011/01/12/sharepoint-2010-site-workflow/

If I assume you are trying to start the workflow on ONE item, this should be easy. You declare a new column on your List which will be used as a "flag" or marker to indicate that it is the one the workflow should search for.

In your Workflow the workflow searches the list for the item with the flag (it can be an integer with value 1) and use that item as "current item".

Hope this helps

Comment: I should have specified: the workflow is affecting multiple list items.

Comment: unfortunatelly in sp2010 there are no loops available in workflows, so the only option i see is to go for different values and selecting each one on its own. Or do you have something like Nintex installed?